# X509Store works different than just MMC+Certificate/Import. What is wrong there?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, pfx, mmc

I have a strange issue with X509Store. I have small tool that adds / removes things from store in pretty classical way:

```
        var pfxContainer = File.ReadAllBytes(strPFXFileName);
        X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxContainer);
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(x509Cert);
            store.Close();
        }
```

Everything will be done from console with admin rights. And everything seems ok – no errors, no exceptions. Certificate is there. Now if I’m trying to choose this certificate from IIS/Binding I become strange message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yacRn.png)
“specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated…”

But certificate is ok - if I'm importing same certificate with MMC – there are no problems at all and I can choose and use this from IIS. Are there some bugs like with certutil.exe and error 87 or I'm missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to work with IIS the certificate must be exportable and include the private key.

To do that you must specify the Exportable and PersistKeySet flags:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(PfxFile, Password,
                        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

Comment: Even if original pfx was written by me and was created with X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet I have to load them into temporal Certificate and recreate them with those flags? Well, this will explain somthing - ill try. Thank you.

Comment: Downvoting, because the certificate don't need to be exportable and the answer is generally is not correct. The OP problem was that certificate was installed in wrong store. It must be installed in `LocalMachine\My` store.

Comment: @Crypt32 The solution worked for the op, so it was the problem. Check this. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/error-hresult-0x80070520-when-adding-ssl-binding-in-iis/ba-p/377281

Comment: This blog post is incorrect, unfortunately. Even Microsoft blogs are not perfect and may contain wrong information. As a part of my job, I manage IIS servers as well and never use exportable keys. What is real problem -- key is stored in wrong place. When importing certificate for IIS, you only need to use `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet`. No exportable.

Comment: Because of `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` flag. There is an old known issue that when creating `X509Certificate2` object from PFX, private key is loaded into an in-memory CSP container which is deleted after all references to private key are removed. A combination of flags I mentioned guarantees that the key persists and persists in machine store and is available to IIS. Export functionality plays no role here.

Comment: I can guarantee marking as Exportable is irrelevant. I'm in the same boat as OP. Regardless if I reimport the PFX through MMC as exportable or not, netsh allows me to bind the certificate (where as before I got the same error as OP).